# What methods should I use to calculate the size of a moving grate incinerator

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering, combustion

I have been tasked with calculating the size of a moving grate incinerator for a college project. I have calculated the mass and energy balances for the waste to be burned on the grate, but I am struggling to find a method for calculating the size. I have found some very rough correlations based on the energy released per unit volume or per unit area but I was wondering if there were any more detailed calculations that I could follow?

So far I calculated the heat released per hour to be 225 000 000 kJ.
Using the correlation (280,000 kJ/m<sup>2</sup>h - 300,000 kJ/m<sup>2</sup>h) for grate area, I found an area of 775m<sup>2</sup> and using the correlation 450- 750 MJ/m<sup>3</sup>/h for furnace volume, I found a volume of 500 m<sup>3</sup>

See working attached.

[image]

Comment: Something doesn't look right with the numbers.  A typical grate length for a moving grate combustor is roughly 10 m, which would mean that your 775 m2 grate is almost 80 m wide.  For the specified throughput it should be 10 to 15 m wide.  Where did you find the grate area and furnace volume criteria?

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. I found it from here: https://www.taylorfrancis.com/chapters/edit/10.1201/b18947-56/waste-energy-combustion-charles-velzy-leonard-grillo

Comment: Do you have any other reliable sources/ a more detailed approach from which I could size the grate?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have anything that I can share.  You must have access to the book you referenced - there are a couple others I'm aware of which may have good information.  Look for https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/EBK1439805039/combustion-incineration-processes-walter-niessen or this has a little information around page 80 https://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.185/epm.300.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/WTE-Guidebook.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much for those. Which rules of thumb do you use to gauge the size of such an incinerator?

Comment: I'm basing this on my familiarity with many of these facilities, and knowing their throughput and approximate grate sizes.  I've checked some notes on a facility which is roughly comparable to the throughput you are asking about, and found that it has a grate size of approx 100 m2, for burning about 30,000 kg/hr of waste with a heating value of about 12,000 kJ/kg.  Based on those numbers it appears that your specific grate area parameter is low by an order of magnitude.